# What transliteration/romanization scheme does Strong's Hebrew Dictionary use?

Tags: ipa, hebrew, lexicon

I can't find anywhere a description of how to convert the Strong Hebrew Dictionary pronunciation transliteration entries into IPA, or a close approximation to IPA. What [romanization scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Hebrew) are they using, so I can figure out how to map it to IPA?

[Here](https://github.com/openscriptures/strongs/blob/master/hebrew/strongs-hebrew-dictionary.js) or [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openscriptures/HebrewLexicon/master/HebrewStrong.xml) (JSON vs. XML) is an example of the dictionary entries, and [here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h759/wlc/wlc/0-1/) is a website showing an entry, which says:

- transliteration: 'armôn
- pronunciation: ar-mone'
- word: אַרְמוֹן

I would think the "transliteration" system is more accurate/useful than their "pronunciation" system, but not sure. Either way, what systems are they using so I can figure out how to convert it automatically to IPA?

Since the Wikipedia [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Hebrew#Examples) section on romanization schemes lists "shalom", I looked it up for [strong's dictionary](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h7965/kjv/wlc/0-1/) and it says "šālôm", which corresponds to "SBL Academic" romanization scheme, is that it? That leads me to [this random page for SBL Academic romanization scheme](http://www.viceregency.com/Translit.htm), but that doesn't seem the same.

**Update**

Yeah it doesn't seem to be SBL academic, because for example [qōḇel](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h6904/kjv/wlc/0-1/) has `ḇ` with an underline below it, but that doesn't exist in the system, and I have seen other examples missing.

Even in [strong's hebrew dictionary itself](https://www.questionsgod.com/word-pdf/strongs-hebrew-dictionary.pdf), I don't see a description of the system used. All it seems to say:

> Immediately after each word is given its exact equivalent in English letters, according
> to the system of transliteration laid down in the scheme here following, which is
> substantially that adopted in the Common English Version, only more consistently and
> uniformly carried out; so that the word could be readily be turned back again into Hebrew
> from the form thus given it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICT it is **SBL academic with spirantization**.

Note that the examples page you linked shows the second word as "ʿălêk̲em", with a `k̲` character (that is, `k` with an underline below it), which does not feature in the page you linked either.
(In fact I cannot see any treatment of the dagesh *at all*; a strange omission.)

Googling "SBL academic romanization" had brought me to [this page](https://hebrewtransliteration.app/), where the transliteration options include "SBL Academic" (the default) and "SBL Academic with Spirantization".
The latter is the version with underlines (as can already be seen in their example, עִבְרִית `ʿiḇrîṯ`, which is unfortunately apparently not a word that occurs in the Bible).

The term "spirantization", in this context, refers to the so-called [Begadkefat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begadkefat), a sound change (a kind of lenition) in Biblical-era Hebrew that was apparently still allophonic in Biblical times but became phonemic later.